# show singular matrix map interior and surface of a unit sphere into an ellipse

Tags: matrices, svd

[The original question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o27bl.png)

A $k$-dimensional ellipse, surface and interior, with axes along the standard coordinates is algebraically defined as the set of points $z = (z_1, \ldots , z_k)^T$ satisfying $(z_1/\alpha_1)^2 + \cdots + (z_k/\alpha_k)^2 \leq 1$.

We can have a $k$-dimensional ellipse embedded inside $\mathbb{R}^n$ even in the case $n > k$ by allowing some of the $z_j$ to be identically zero. Using these definitions, show that the matrix $\Sigma = \text{diag}(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_{\min(m,n)}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, where $\sigma_1 \geq \ldots \geq \sigma_{\min (m,n)} \geq 0$, maps the unit sphere $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_2 \leq 1\}$, surface and interior, to an ellipse.

**Under what conditions is the surface of the unit sphere mapped to the surface of the ellipse?** (Suggestion: Consider the cases $m \geq n$ and $n > m$ separately. Also, some of the axes of the ellipse may be zero, so it may be convenient to introduce $r \leq \min(m,n)$ such that $\sigma_1 \geq \ldots \geq \sigma_r > 0$.)

I think this is like a SVD question and I found the page here that might be useful: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.3603&rep=rep1&type=pdf

But I still do not quite understand the exact process of mapping the interior and surface of a unit sphere into an ellipse, maybe SVD is doing what I am asking?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a good question, and you've phrased it well. The answer basically has nothing to do with the SVD; it's setting up a more general claim fpor use with the SVD. Here are some questions to ask yourself (and perhaps to answer for yourself in your question, by clicking "edit" at the bottom). Focus on $n = m = 3$ to start.  Suppose $T(x) = \Sigma x$, where $x \in \Bbb R^n$. (1) What does it mean (in coordinates) for $x$ to be on or within the unit sphere? (2) Now look at $T(x)$ (in coordinates): what's it mean for $T(x)$ to be on/within the unit sphere? What about on/within the ellipse?

Comment: When you've answered those, consider $n = 3, m = 2$. And in both cases, assume that all the $\sigma$s are positive -- you can work on the $\sigma_i = 0$ cases after you've got the generic case worked out!

Answer (score 0):

just take an arbitrary point on the surface of the unit sphere, and apply the transformation to it. There will be a condition that results in the transformed point taking on a form of a k-dimensional ellipse.

-Ivo